# How to perform database operations in the tearDown() method in a Quarkus Reactive test?

Tags: junit, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

Although there is the `@TestTransaction` annotation, it does not seem to work in my case.

For that reason I like to manually clean the database after each test, using the tearDown method of JUnit.

However, I can't inject a `UniAsserter` like in test methods, and I also can't use `@WithSession` / `@WithTransaction` on this method, as it needs to return a **Uni**.

Also using the `Mutiny.SessionFactory` causes problems:

```
    @Inject
    FileRepository fileRepository;

    @Inject
    Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @AfterEach
    @Blocking
    @RunOnVertxContext
    void tearDown() {
        sessionFactory.withSession(session -> fileRepository.deleteAll()).await().indefinitely();
    }
```

produces

> The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-3

What do I have to do in order to call `fileRepository.deleteAll()` in the **tearDown()** method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a dedicated `@TestReactiveTransaction` that has to be used instead of the `@TestTransaction` method when working with Quarkus Reactive.

I also noticed that those tests using **Restassured** don't need it at all.

So there is no need to use the **tearDown** for my case at all.

**However, I'd still appreciate to see a solution if there is any.**

Comment: Correct, `@TestReactiveTransaction` is what should be used.